# Struct elements as parameter in a function C programming

Tags: c, pointers, struct, structure, dma

Im new to programming and im having a hard time learning about allocating memory on the heap and trying to work with structs and pointer at the same time.
This is what im trying to achieve:

- create a struct called student with 2 pointers elements to strings that im tring to allocate on the heap
- create a function that gets input from the user and saves the input in the elements of the struct on the heap
- create a function that prints all the values from the struct on the heap

```
#include <stdio.h>

   struct student
 { 
    char * name;
    char * course;
 };

//function prototypes
void getStudentInfo(struct student *pStu, pStu->name, pStu->course);
void printInfo(struct student springClass[]);


int main(){
//create an array of 5 students
struct student springClass[5];

for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    getStudentInfo(struct student springClass[i], springClass[i].name, springClass[i].course);
}

printInfo(struct student springClass)

//free memory
free(p1);

return 0;
}


// function that gets input from the user and saves the input in the elements of the struct on the heap

void getStudentInfo(struct student *pStu, pStu->name, pStu->course)
{
    struct student *p1 {NULL}; 

       //create memory on the heap
     p1 = (struct student *) malloc( 2 * (31 * sizeof(char)));  // for 1 names strings and 1 course string

     //get input from user

         printf("Enter name: ");
         fgets(p1->name, 31, stdin);
         printf("Enter course: ");
         fgets(p1->course, 31, stdin);

}

void printInfo(struct student springClass[])
{
     for(int i=; i < 5; i++)
     {
        printf("Student #%d Name: %s\n", i+1, springClass[i].name);
        printf("Student #%d course: %s\n", i+1, springClass[i].course);
        printf("==========================================\n");
     }
}
```

I would really apreciate your help in anyways, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I fixed some major bugs in your code. First of all, you can use the 'typedef' to declare a spcified object with a specified name, it allows you to note repeat the struct name over and over. Second, Organize your code properly.

In my code, you can see I used the stdlib library to initate functions as calloc which is malloc but it initializes all the allocated bytes with 0 (especially useful with strings, as you should always initialize everything with 0 there!).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student
{
    char* name;
    char* course;
} student;

//function prototypes
void getStudentInfo(student* pStu);
void printInfo(student* springClass);


int main() {
    //create an array of 5 students
    student* springClass = (student *)calloc(5, sizeof(student));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        getStudentInfo(springClass + i);
    }

    printInfo(springClass);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        free(springClass[i].name);
        free(springClass[i].course);
    }

    free(springClass);

    return 0;
}


// function that gets input from the user and saves the input in the elements of the struct on the heap

void getStudentInfo(student* pStu)
{
    //create memory on the heap
    //get input from user

    printf("Enter name: ");
    pStu->name = (char*)calloc(31, sizeof(char));
    fgets(pStu->name, 31, stdin);
    printf("Enter course: ");
    pStu->course = (char*)calloc(31, sizeof(char));
    fgets(pStu->course, 31, stdin);
    printf("\n");
}

void printInfo(student* springClass)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Student #%d Name: %s\n", i + 1, springClass[i].name);
        printf("Student #%d course: %s\n", i + 1, springClass[i].course);
        printf("==========================================\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to use the "free" function, we will need to include stdlib.h as well:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

when you are passing a struct as a parameter to a function, you do not need to specify the elements within that struct. When you defined your struct at the top as:

```
struct student
    { 
    char * name;
    char * course;
    };
```

This is where you are telling the compiler everything it needs to know about that struct. So in your getStudentInfo prototype, you only need to do:

```
void getStudentInfo(struct student *pStu);
```

---

Now, let's head to your main function.

Currently, you aren't allocating the student objects on the heap.

```
struct student springClass[5];
```

This code is instead making room for 5 student structs, in an array, on the stack. If you want these objects to be in the heap, you must allocate them dynamically with malloc, just as you are doing with the user inputs:

```
struct student *springClass = malloc ( 5 * sizeof(struct student) );
```

If you know beforehand how many students there will be, it would be better to stick with your current method. However, dynamic allocation is generally good for when you don't know the specific amount.

Note: "Dynamic allocation" refers to allocating space in the heap "dynamically", or while the program is running. It is dynamic because it is able to change on the fly.

Anyway, in your loop to put data into all 5 of these structs, we reformatted the getStudentInfo function to only accept a "struct student pointer" as a parameter. This is the location in memory where our student is that we currently want to add. In C, you retrieve the address of something by pre-pending it with the "&", or ampersand symbol. I like to remember this by thinking that "address" starts with an A, just like "ampersand". It's not a very strong comparison, but it's the best I've got :)

Because we want a pointer to the address of our current student, we pass in "&springClass[i]". Additionally, because we already told the compiler what the getStudentInfo receives, we don't need to tell it again, we can simply give it the value. All-in-all, inside the loop, we make the call like this:

```
getStudentInfo( &springClass[i] );
```

If you would like to read more about pointers, along with the * and & symbols, [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) provides a good explanation.

Now, after the loop we also have the call to printInfo. Similarly to the getStudentInfo call earlier, here we don't need to tell the function what kind of thing we're giving it, so there is no need to specify "struct student":

```
printInfo(springClass);
```

And finally, freeing up the memory we allocated earlier. Please note that if you don't allocate memory with the "malloc" function, and instead use "int array[10];", for example, this memory will be on the stack. When you exit a function, memory that is on the stack will be automatically freed, so you need not worry about freeing it explicitly.

Note: This memory being automatically freed can also cause problems if you attempt to use it outside of that function. For example, if you allocate some memory on the stack, then return a pointer to that memory, you will get a segmentation fault. The reason for this is that your memory was automatically freed when you returned (This is called "going out of scope"). And thus, that pointer would now point to memory that no longer is valid.

However, if you do decide to allocate your springClass list on the heap, you will need to use the "free" function. However, we cannot tell it to free "p1", as that is something which we have defined inside of the getStudentInfo function. Memory, as well as variable names, are bound by the "scope" that they are defined inside. This means that we can use the variable "p1" inside of GetStudentInfo, but if we attempt to use it anywhere else, the compiler won't know what we're talking about. Instead, we need to free the array as a whole, like:

```
free( springClass );
```

But wait, there's more!

Since we malloc'd all of the elements of each struct in this array, we also need to go inside of it and free all of those individually.

Important note: free() is not recursive!

So let's iterate over the list again, this time freeing things up, until finally freeing the entire list:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
    free( springClass[i].name );
    free( springClass[i].course );
    }

free( springClass );
```

---

Phew, alright, onto the next function. However, I would like to quickly point out that, in programming, it is often good practice to look at your functions in isolation.

> "What are this function's parameters?"
>
> "What does this function need to return?"
>
> "How do we do that with our given parameters?"

If you look at each function on its own, it can help with not getting overwhelmed. This is also part of why people like to advocate for keeping your functions small: Not only can long functions be hard to read, they get confusing and become a pain to debug later. This is also why I finished looking over the entirety of your main function at one time instead of moving to the other functions when you called them.

Anyway, we're almost done. The final two functions need only minimal fixing up. First of all, this one begins similarly to how we adjusted the prototype:

```
void getStudentInfo(struct student *pStu) {
...
}
```

And, since we have already allocated this student object, either on the stack or in the heap does not matter, we simply access its data members through the pointer we have been given. However, we do still need to allocate space for the strings the user will be inputting. So, we do this:

```
pStu->name = malloc( 31 * sizeof( char ) );
pStu->class = malloc( 31 * sizeof( char ) );
```

You can allocate both at the same time, but I don't recommend that quite yet. Once you learn how to actually use pointers and dynamic memory, you can then learn ways to optimize its use.

The final function becomes:

```
void getStudentInfo(struct student *pStu)
    {
    // Allocate memory on the stack
    pStu->name = malloc( 31 * sizeof(char) );
    pStu->class = malloc( 31 * sizeof(char) );

    // Get input from user
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets( pStu->name, 31, stdin);
    printf("Enter course: ");
    fgets( pStu->course, 31, stdin);

    }
```

---

Other than a small typo (Using "int i=;" instead of "int i = 0;"), I see nothing wrong with your final function. While there is a better way to write it, I don't feel it's important to get into, as right now you should focus on just understanding everything you write.

---

Here is my complete code. Please only use it as a reference, it is important to do it yourself and understand what is going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

   struct student
 {
    char * name;
    char * course;
 };


//function prototypes
void getStudentInfo(struct student *pStu);
void printInfo(struct student springClass[]);


int main(){
    //create an array of 5 students
    struct student* springClass = malloc(5 * sizeof(struct student));

    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        getStudentInfo(&springClass[i]);
    }

    printInfo(springClass);

    //free memory
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        {
        free( springClass[i].name );
        free( springClass[i].course );
    }
    free( springClass );

    return 0;
}


// function that gets input from the user and saves the input in the elements of the struct on the heap

void getStudentInfo(struct student *pStu)
{
    // Allocate memory on the stack
    pStu->name = malloc( 31 * sizeof(char) );
    pStu->course = malloc( 31 * sizeof(char) );

    // Get input from user
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets( pStu->name, 31, stdin);
    printf("Enter course: ");
    fgets( pStu->course, 31, stdin);

}

void printInfo(struct student springClass[])
    {
    for(int i=0 ; i < 5; i++)
        {
        printf("Student #%d Name: %s\n", i+1, springClass[i].name);
        printf("Student #%d course: %s\n", i+1, springClass[i].course);
        printf("==========================================\n");
        }
}
```

There are some style differences between Sean and my answers, but both should work. I apologize for the very lengthy answer, but as you are new to programming I felt it may be useful to go into more detail than would normally be necessary. Hope it helps!

Edit: Added the free of student->name and student->class at end of main as per Sean's recommend.

Comment: thank you so much for your response, i REALLY apreciate it! can't thank you enough

Comment: Just saying, you're not freeing the 'name' and 'course' variables at the end of you main...

Comment: Whoops! Put that in my main body but not in the code at the end, thank you!